# NestedScrollView of can't scroll smoothly in CoodinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout, android-viewpager2, android-nestedscrollview

When I use NestedScrollView in CoordinatorLayout as below, I can't scroll smoothly in ViewPager2.Sometimes it works, But only when I scroll fast. Where am I wrong? Any help would be appreciated

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
            android:background="@color/white">
        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary"
                app:toolbarId="@+id/title_toolbar"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary">
            <!-- somethin -->
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true">
        <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                android:id="@+id/view_pager"></androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?android:actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:layout_behavior=".ui.NavBehavior"
            android:id="@+id/main_nav_container">
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52083678/nestedscrollviews-smoothscrollto-behaves-weird) helps?

Comment: no, still can't work